# Push method for Stack with Nodes

Tags: java, stack, nodes

I am having trouble doing a homework assignment involving stacks and nodes in Java. I understand the concept of Stacks but am confused with Nodes. The assignment is to make a program using Stacks (Not java.util.Stack) that checks a mathematical expression for correct pairs of (), [], and {}s. We already have the Node program.
So basically my problem is I would like some help completing the Push Method of my PStack class.

### PStack.java

```
class PStack {
    private Node top;


    public PStack() {
        top=null;
    }
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return top==null;
    }
    public int pop() {
        Node top1 = top;
        top = top.getNext();
        return top1.getData();


    }
    public void push(Node n) {
        



    }
    public int peek() {
        return top.getData();
    }

}
```

### Node.java

```
public class Node {
    private int data;
    private Node nextnode;
    public Node(int intial) {
        data = intial;
        nextnode = null;
    }

    public int getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public Node getNext() {
        return nextnode;
    }

    public void setData(int newdata) {

        data = newdata;
    }

    public void setNode(Node next1node) {

        nextnode = next1node;
    }

}
```

I tried:

```
public void push(Node n) {
    Node next = n;
    top.getNext().setNode(n);


}
```

Result:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javaclass.stack.pStack.push(pStack.java:24)
    at javaclass.stack.StackDriver.main(StackDriver.java:17)
```

Comment: It’s not clear what the issue is.

Comment: @DaveNewton i updated my post with the problem.

Comment: That didn’t help (me, anyway :) Is there a specific problem with one of the classes? Is it an issue of not knowing how to use them to solve this particular problem (which is a common problem to solve with a stack since it turns it into a few-line solution)?

Comment: Aside: please follow the Java coding conventions.  Class names should start with a capital letter.  `pStack` should be `PStack`.

Comment: If you want help implementing `push()`, you'll have to at least make an attempt.  I doubt anyone is just going to write it for you.  If you're completely stuck then please ask your instructor for help, they need to know that you are struggling.

Comment: @markspace alright then i'll update the post with code I tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public void push(Node n) {
    n.setNode(top);
    top = n;
}
```

*Edit:*

BTW, this is an odd implementation of a stack. It looks like it wants to be a stack of int primitives. Both peek() and pop() return an int. But then push takes an argument that should be an internal construct of the stack itself. It shouldn't take a Node object as an argument. It should take an int argument and wrap it with the Node object internally.

Also, Node.setNode should be named Node.setNext. It's just more consistent with what you are doing. A linked list node has a "next" member and a double linked list node has "next" and "previous" members. The getters and setters of the node object should be appropriately named for those members.

Like this:

*PStack.java*

```
public class PStack {
    private Node top;

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return top==null;
    }

    public int pop() {
        Node top1 = top;
        top = top.getNext();
        return top1.getData();
    }

    public void push(int data) {
        Node newtop = new Node(data);
        newtop.setNext(top);
        top = newtop;
    }

    public int peek() {
        return top.getData();
    }
}
```

*Node.java*

```
public class Node {
    private int data;
    private Node next;

    public Node(int data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public int getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public Node getNext() {
        return next;
    }

    public void setNext(Node next) {
        this.next = next;
    }
}
```